# How to recursively exit nested shells?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, zsh

I use the [Ranger](https://github.com/ranger/ranger) file manager in my terminal to move around. Every time I use the `S` command to drop into a new directory, Ranger is actually launching a new shell. When I want to close a terminal window I need to run `exit` as many times as I have changed directories with Ranger. Is there a command that will run `exit` recursively for me until the window closes? Or better yet is there a different Ranger command to use?

Comment: Try using ENTER to enter a directory

Comment: ENTER opens the directory in Ranger, but I'm looking to open it back in my shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't enter a sub-shell, just quit ranger and let the shell sync the directory back from ranger.

```sh
function ranger {
    local IFS=$'\t\n'
    local tempfile="$(mktemp -t tmp.XXXXXX)"
    local ranger_cmd=(
        command
        ranger
        --cmd="map Q chain shell echo %d > "$tempfile"; quitall"
    )

    ${ranger_cmd[@]} "$@"
    if [[ -f "$tempfile" ]] && [[ "$(cat -- "$tempfile")" != "$PWD" ]]; then
        cd -- "$(cat "$tempfile")" || return
    fi
    command rm -f -- "$tempfile" 2>/dev/null
}
```

Press **capital** <kbd>Q</kbd> to quit ranger, after which the shell will sync directory automatically to the same one within ranger.

This is very **flexible** and you can use <kbd>q</kbd> to quit normally **without** syncing the dir back to the shell.

**Update**:

`. ranger` to open ranger is another solution, which is NOT recommended. Because compared with previous method, quitting from `. ranger` with <kbd>q</kbd> will always sync the dir back to the shell from ranger. You have no control on this behavior.

> No real solution to this. It's oft requested but not as easy as people think.
>   You can source ranger, so start it like this `. ranger`. That'll cd to ranger's cwd when quitting.

References

- [Changing directories from ranger wiki](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/wiki/Integration-with-other-programs#changing-directories)
- [How to exit and cd into last dir you were on ranger? #1554](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/issues/1554)

Comment: Thank you so much for this function! I was wrong all along when using `S` to drop into the desired dir.

Answer (score 1):

@Simba thanks for the great answer and the link to the docs.

In the end, the easiest answer was to just create an alias in my `.bashrc` like the docs recommend

```sh
alias ranger=". ranger"
```

Now when I use `Q` to quit, it automatically switches to the new directory, and only requires running `exit` one time to close the window.

Comment: I've known this solution already from [issue 1554](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/issues/1554). The drawback of this solution is that, quitting with `q` will always sync the directory back to the shell. And you have no control on this behavior at all. This is also the reason why the custom function method is provided in this issue.

Comment: I just noticed that, that makes my fix a deal breaker, I'll go ahead and mark your original answer as correct, that one solves it for real.